# Javascript How to reset a value to original

Tags: javascript, html

How can i reset values i have set in a function back to the original values?

For example what i have is a value of 10
In a function i select something and that changes the value (+2) to 12, but when i select someting else that should change the value (+5) to 15 what happends is that it adds the 5 on top of the 12 instead of first setting the original value back to 10.
The same with the example code, when i chose Dwarf it should reset the changes in value made by Dragonborn.

```javascript
function pRace(playerRace) {
    var race = playerRace.value;
    if (race == 'Dragonborn') {
        document.getElementById("strScore").value = 
                parseInt(document.getElementById("strScore").value) + 2;
        document.getElementById("chaScore").value = parseInt(document.getElementById("chaScore").value) + 1;
    } else if (race == 'Dwarf') {

        document.getElementById("conScore").value = parseInt(document.getElementById("conScore").value) + 2;
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess you should store the original values somewhere...

Comment: You could store the values as part of the element's dataset attributes - see [Using data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes)

Comment: Need improvement on the question

Comment: you can preserve values in any temporary hidden element.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `dataset` property on each input to store the previous value. This way you could extrapolate a delta using the previous value and the current.

The example below heavily modifies the form every time there is a change. You could instead use a view/model and validate the values on the object instead.

```js
const statForm = document.forms['stats'];
const defaultStats = { str: 10, con: 10, dex: 10, int: 10, wis: 10, cha: 10 };
const character = {
  stats: { ...defaultStats },
  allocated: 0,
  pool: 7
};

const main = () => {
  on('.reset-all', 'click', onResetAll);
  on('.reset', 'click', onReset);
  on('.stat input', 'change', onStatChange);

  resetForm(statForm);
};

const displayStats = () => {
  console.log(Object.entries(character)
    .map(([k, v]) => `${k} ${JSON.stringify(v)}`)
    .join('\n'));
};

const adjustMaxRange = () => {
  const remaining = character.pool - character.allocated;
  for (let stat in defaultStats) {
    const newMax = parseInt(statForm[stat].value, 10) + remaining;
    statForm[stat].setAttribute('max', newMax);
  }
  displayStats();
};

const resetForm = (form) => {
  for (let stat in defaultStats) {
    const defaultValue = defaultStats[stat];
    form[stat].value = character.stats[stat] = defaultValue;
    form[stat].dataset.prevValue = defaultValue;
    form[stat].setAttribute('min', defaultValue);
  }
  character.allocated = 0;
  adjustMaxRange();
};

const onStatChange = (e) => {
  const input = e.target;
  const prevValue = parseInt(input.dataset.prevValue);
  const currValue = parseInt(input.value, 10);
  const delta = currValue > prevValue ? 1 : -1;
  input.dataset.prevValue = currValue;
  character.stats[input.name] = currValue;
  character.allocated += delta;
  adjustMaxRange();
};

const onReset = e => {
  const input = e.target.parentElement.querySelector('input');
  const stat = input.name;
  const currValue = parseInt(input.value, 10);
  const defaultValue = defaultStats[stat];
  const delta = currValue - defaultValue;
  statForm[stat].value = character.stats[stat] = defaultValue;
  input.dataset.prevValue = defaultValue;
  character.allocated -= delta;
  adjustMaxRange();
};

const onResetAll = e => resetForm(statForm);

const on = (selector, eventName, handler) =>
  document.querySelectorAll(selector).forEach(e =>
    e.addEventListener(eventName, handler));

main();
```

```css
.stats {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 25%;
}
.stat {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  margin-bottom: 0.25em;
}

.stats, .stats .stat *, .stats button { font-size: smaller; }

.stat label { flex: 1 }
.stat input { width: 4em;  }
.stat button { width: 4em; margin-left: 0.33em; }

/* Stack Snippet */
.as-console-wrapper {
  position: absolute !important;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: unset !important;
  bottom: unset !important;
  max-height: 99vh !important;
  width: 72%;
  margin: 0;
  border-top: none !important;
}
.as-console .as-console-row-code,
.as-console .as-console-row:after {
  font-size: smaller;
}
```

```html
<form name="stats" class="stats" onsubmit="return false;">
  <div class="stat">
    <label>Strength</label>
    <input type="number" name="str" />
    <button class="reset">Reset</button>
  </div>
  <div class="stat">
    <label>Constitution</label>
    <input type="number" name="con" />
    <button class="reset">Reset</button>
  </div>
  <div class="stat">
    <label>Dexterity</label>
    <input type="number" name="dex" />
    <button class="reset">Reset</button>
  </div>
  <div class="stat">
    <label>Intelligence</label>
    <input type="number" name="int" />
    <button class="reset">Reset</button>
  </div>
  <div class="stat">
    <label>Wisdom</label>
    <input type="number" name="wis" />
    <button class="reset">Reset</button>
  </div>
  <div class="stat">
    <label>Charisma</label>
    <input type="number" name="cha" />
    <button class="reset">Reset</button>
  </div>
  <button class="reset-all">Reset All</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can set for example array or obj with default values, and get this values when you need it. `const defaultAttributes = {str: 10, con: 10, dex: 10, int: 10, wis: 10, cha: 10}`